# multiple profiles for people that connect through multiple authentication providers

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

So if you have multiple authentication methods, and people connect via those sources, they will have a profile for each authentication method.  There **absolutely has to** be multiple authentication sources for this SharePoint instance, and people must be able to connect via each.

My question is, has anyone successfully mapped two authentication sources to one profile?  If so, how?

If this is truly not possible, would you mind explaining why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most only have a single profile for any one individual. SharePoint sees the identity as two different users, and they cannot be 'merged' together.

If you are unable to switch to a single provider for all Web Applications/users, you may want to look at one UPA Service Application per Web Application.

To give you an example, you may have a user come through Active Directory (Windows auth) and the same user come via SAML (e.g. ADFS). With the Windows auth user, SharePoint is able to store the SID of the object (SystemUserKey) and use that as the identifier along with their sAMAccountName. For ADFS, the user is only seen via the attribute used for authentication, e.g. 'mail'. They are two different users as far as an authorization system is concerned.

Comment: If a user has multiple profiles depending on whether the user logged in via AD or ADFS, it seems to defeat the purpose of SSO.   Why is this a problem for Microsoft systems?

Comment: Why are you using ADFS and Windows Auth? Just use ADFS (and perhaps WAP + ADFS if you need FBA style logins). SSO is provided by a service, such as ADFS, that allows you to log into multiple systems. IE provides "SSO" by simply passing your Windows user/pass to a system that requests it, given it is in the Intranet Zone. It isn't true SSO.

Comment: This is for a hospital with kiosks.  The kiosks are logged in with a generic user account.  They want FBA so that people can log in to SharePoint with their own credentials; since these are kiosks, multiple nurses and doctors may walk up to the kiosk.  Many (but not all) of the users also have their own desktops in which they log in via Windows Credentials.  I am looking to enable both of these scenarios.  Would WAP + ADFS give me one login that supports both these scenarios?  Thank you for the tip!

Comment: WAP + ADFS 3.0 will present a forms-based login scenario. You can also configure ADFS to use a non-claims aware relaying party trust so you do not have to configure SharePoint to use SAML.

Comment: In this circumstance, is everyone using the forms based login and the windows auth disappears?

Comment: No, SharePoint is configured to use Windows Auth, but users are pointed at WAP in order to access SharePoint. Great how-to on this: http://www.brightstarr.com/sharepoint-technology-and-application-insights/securely-publishing-sharepoint-externally-using-web-application-proxy-part-2

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm still a little unclear how this resolves my issue and I think I might have just asked the question incorrectly. In the scenario you described, are users authenticating to the system only via ADFS and WAP? If so, how do I prevent them from authenticating via windows auth? Even doing deny all on the web app would just send them to a request access page instead of the ADFS login. What am I missing?

Comment: They're always logging in with Windows Auth, whether it is via WAP or directly to SharePoint. But you point the A record for your Web App at WAP so your users are directed to it.